# JSON object with single quotes without escape characters

Tags: python, json, string

I am trying to create son object out of the raw string that I receive in real time stream for processing.
 String I am processing is:

```
{‘check_1’:{‘key_1’:15017.118,‘key_2’:’HTTPConnectionPool(host=‘host_1’, port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)’,’key_3’:’Some reason here’}}
```

I am trying to replace the single quote with the double quotes with something like

```
str = str.replace(",'", ',"').replace("',", '",')
str = str.replace(":'", ':"').replace("':", '":')
str = str.replace("{'", '{"').replace("'}", '"}')
```

but value for `key_2` is causing the problem when I do `json.loads(str)` because value of `key_2` has multiple single quotes.

One way I am thinking is using regex with back propagation.
Is there is any other way to convert this type of strings into son object.

Comment: Do you have control over the source? It seems to be sending invalid JSON.

Comment: None of your items and keys are contained by quotes notice: `'` you are using the apostrophe key I think its called. The one next to your 1

Comment: for key2, you have an space between finishing key1 and starting key2. So you are missing one replace: .replace(", '", ', "')

Comment: Besides the value of `key_2` being ill-formed because it's missing a close quote. The string is using Unicode opening and closing single quotation marks not single quotes (aka apostrophes), so your replace calls to replace them with double quotes won't work.

Comment: Specific quote characters aside (unless they really are left- and right- quotation mark pairs), you have nested quotes that are going to be difficult to treat properly. This is a bug in the producer, and it should be fixed.

Comment: See [ASCII and Unicode quotation marks](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) for more info about what I said previously regarding the quotation marks being used. FWIW I also agree with @chepner that the best solution would be to fix the source of these strings rather that the bogus output it's producing.

Comment: That **isn't** JSON at all. It's only JSON if it complies with the specification, and the specification doesn't allow single quotes. Fix the program producing it to actually generate JSON, and `json.loads()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

This quick hack with re library seems to work

```py
import re
thestring = re.sub(r'[‘’]', '"', thestring) # don't call your variable str
thestring = re.sub(r'="(\S+)"', r"='\1'", thestring)
print( json.loads(thestring))
```

Comment: My bad, first replacement is with double quotes, then single quotes when encounters a "=" symbol.
Fixed

Comment: it's not valid json and even you convert all single ' to " how it would be object as there would multiple " inside "